# Proper setup of Pycharm, Git and Github

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I'm using the current version of Pycharm (2017.3.2) and am using it to develop some pretty ordinary Python 3 programs to analyze text files.  I would like to have the projects on GitHub, and I can't make sense of the setup instructions.  I've used SCCSs like Perforce, but this is my first venture into Git.

It *appears* that the recommended setup is Pycharm using a local installation of Git as its repository, and then having the local Git repository linked to GitHub so that changes can be committed locally even when offline and then committed from there to GitHub.  Is this correct or am I confused?  (Can anyone recommend a good reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official PyCharm [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-git-integration.html) should suffice.

From personal experience, I've seen that if you open up in Pycharm a project that is already tracked in `git` then Pycharm automatically finds and shows git related info (e.g. history, commits etc) in the version control [panel](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/version-control-with-pycharm.html). The version control panel is updated with the latest info, every time you perform a git-related activity, such as `git commit`. However, if you want to do this via Pycharm's integrated git tool (and not via the standard git cli) then you'll have to follow the above instructions to see how you can register you `git` account in Pycharm.

Comment: Thank you.  I eventually figured this out -- the key point I missed was that Pycharm creates a local Git repository for each project, but I never came back here since the only response my question got was a downvote. Apparently I shouldn't have wanted to know that.  In any event, thanks for answering!